# The shop is closed. Can I use "The shop's closed"

Tags: grammar

Excersice from Merphy "Essention Grammer in Use".
There is only "The shop IS closed" in answer. Can I use short version: The shop's closed?

Answer (score 3):

Spoken and informal written English use contractions all the time.

> The shop’s closed

is perfectly idiomatic English.

Formal written English avoids contractions except in direct quotation.

> The shop’s closed

is not acceptable in formal written English.

> The shop is closed

is acceptable and comprehensible in English, whether spoken or written, whether informal or formal.

The book gave the answer that is always acceptable rather than the answer that is usually but not always acceptable.